# How do I validate dynamically added textFields on a button click in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following InputView struct and add those InputViews dynamically within a foreach loop in another view:

```
struct InputView: View {

@State private var input: String = ""
var correct_input: Int

var body: some View {
    TextField("?", text: $input)
        .foregroundColor(setColor())
}

func setColor() -> Color {
    
    if (Int(input) == correct_input) {
        return Color.green
    }
    return Color.red
}
}
```

Up to now it is shown immediately whether the input is correct. However, I would like to add a button so that the input of all InputViews is only validated when it is clicked. How can I achieve this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be done this by making a model of text fields and use one isValid flag for each InputView for the track.

Here, is the possible demo solution.

```
struct TextFieldModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var input: String
    var correctInput: Int
    var isValidate: Bool = true
}

struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var input: TextFieldModel
    var body: some View {
        TextField("?", text: $input.input)
            .foregroundColor(input.isValidate ? Color.blue : Color.red)
    }
}

struct ContentViewTextFields: View {
    @State var arrTextFields: [TextFieldModel] = [
        .init(input: "", correctInput: 5),
        .init(input: "", correctInput: 10),
        .init(input: "", correctInput: 1)
    ]
    
    @State var isValidate: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(arrTextFields.indices) { index in
                InputView(input: $arrTextFields[index])
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .padding()
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Validate") {
                // Here validate all text
                arrTextFields.indices.forEach({arrTextFields[$0].isValidate = (Int(arrTextFields[$0].input) == arrTextFields[$0].correctInput) })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you achieve that with dynamically generated views? I am struggling storing these into an array after creating them.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? If you create dynamic it will sure have array. Please add some more details

Comment: Let's say sometimes I want to have 3 Textfields and other times 5 or 8. I have a foreach loop in the body of my View like this: 

ForEach(viewModel.digits, id: \.self, content: { correct_input in
       InputView(correct_input: correct_input)
})

Is it somehow possible to append those InputViews to my array?

Comment: I suggest you to convert your digit model with this so at the end you can use this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can have a button to check the input, setting some `@State` variable like `correct` to `true` if it is correct.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        InputView(correctInput: 5)
    }
}

struct InputView: View {
    @State private var input = ""
    @State private var correct = false
    let correctInput: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("?", text: $input)
                .foregroundColor(correct ? .green : .red)
            
            Button("Check answer") {
                correct = Int(input) == correctInput
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to have a single check button for all my views. :)

Comment: @flo I'm unsure what you mean. Do you have lots of `InputView`s and would like to check them all at same time instead of individually?