# Use object property as binding variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct called `Answer` which holds a couple properties, one of which is `value: String?`. In my SwiftUI app, I ask the user to enter their answer into a textfield from which I'd then like to save the result in the answer object – something like this:

```swift
struct Answer {
    var id: Int
    var value: String?
}

var answers: [Answer]!

var body: some View {
    ForEach(answers, id: \.id) { answer in
        TextField("Answer \(id.string) here", text: $answer.value)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. Error message:

> Cannot find '$answer' in scope

What I'd not like to do is create a separate `@State` variable for each answer, because I'm asking a whole bunch of questions and thus want to save a lot of answers (which I get from an API, so I don't know which / how many answers there will be).

How do I implement such a thing?

Comment: With swift 5.5 you can bind variables to each element in the array but in earlier versions I believe looping over the array using indices is the most common solution. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340575/binding-and-foreach-in-swiftui.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you show me how?

Comment: you can use class with ObservableObjects protocols, and make answer as @published property.

Comment: You can take dynamic TextField reference from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67950131/14733292

Comment: Awesome, thanks RajaKishan & JoakimDanielson, this is exactly what I was looking for!