# Create an arbitrary number of state variables in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a survey using SwiftUI, where the survey can have an arbitrary number of questions.

[image]

I'm trying to capture what values the user inputted through state variables such as:

```
@State var answer: String = ""

ForEach(survey) { surveyQuestion in
  Text(surveyQuestion.question)

  TextField(surveyQuestion.placeholder, text: $answer)
}
```

However, since I don't know how many questions are going to be in the survey beforehand, I don't know how many of these state variables to store the answers to make. I could create the variables on the fly inside the ForEach loop but then the variables would be out of scope when I actually go to submit the survey (since the submitting would happen outside of the ForEach loop).

**How do I create an arbitrary number of state variables to capture the user's answers to the survey?**

EDIT: I had tried making my answers variable a dictionary, where the keys are the IDs to the questions. My code looked like:

```
@State var answers: [String:String] = [:]

ForEach(survey) { surveyQuestion in
  Text(surveyQuestion.question)

  TextField(surveyQuestion.placeholder, text: $answers[surveyQuestion.id!])
}
```

However, I kept getting the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

So then I tried replacing `$answers[surveyQuestion.id!]` with `$(answers[surveyQuestion.id!]!)` but then the system gets confused and responds with:

```
'$' is not an identifier; use backticks to escape it
```

I had also tried adjusting my question model so that there's a field for an answer in the same struct. My code looked like this:

```
TextField(surveyQuestion.placeholder, text: $surveyQuestion.answer)
```

I kept getting the error:

```
Cannot find '$surveyQuestion' in scope
```

Comment: Does this your ansere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67950131/14733292

Comment: Your choice of how you want to approach this might depend on what you intend to do with this data later on. A couple of possibilities I can think of: 1) Adjust your question model so that there's a field for an answer in the same struct/object. 2) Make your `answers` variable a Dictionary where the keys are the IDs of the questions. 3) Make your `answers` variable an array, where you append each new answer to the end of it.

Comment: You should not use `@State` variable for holding the information about the questions. @State is really only _internal_ state that a view _may_ need to add its "opinionated flavour" when rendering the actual model. The actual _view state_ will be set from the outside and contains the _whole truth_, i.e. your Q&A as a list and any additional data that directly affects the visual and directly affects what the view should render. The _view state_ can be modelled as a simple let constant AND user actions will be passed via functions to a view model performing the logic and emitting the view state.

Comment: @jnpdx I had tried those options but none of them worked :( I edited my post above to show what I tried and what errors I got. 

I'm just trying to collect all the survey answers and, once the user clicks submit, push the answers up to Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the strategy in the edit that you added, with the Dictionary, you could provide a custom Binding, like this:

```
func bindingForID(id: String) -> Binding<String> {
    .init {
        answers[id] ?? ""
    } set: { newValue in
        answers[id] = newValue
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
TextField(surveyQuestion.placeholder, text: bindingForID(id: surveyQuestion.id))
```

In terms of adding this data to Firestore, you *could* trigger Firestore updates in the `set` closure from the custom binding. However, I'd probably recommend moving this logic to a `@Published` property on a view model (`ObservableObject`) where you could use Combine to do things like Debouncing before you send the data to Firestore (probably a little beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct that holds id, question, and answer. Your @State var should be an array of those.

```
struct QA: Identifiable {
id: String
question: String
answer: String
}

…

@State private var myQAs: [QA] = myQAs() // or populate them in init, onAppear(if asynchronous) or however you see fit

…
ForEach(myQAs) { qa in
  Text(qa.question)

  TextField(placeholder, text: $qa.answer)
}
```